# How to fix jump is not a function error (Kaboom.js)?

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio, kaboom

I was trying to create a small flappy bird clone but I've run in into this error which I can't fix. Also I'm using VS Code, if that matters.

Error:

```
    TypeError: player.jump is not a function
        at Object.cb (https://68045eae-6558-4e68-bc51-31bc244469a3.id.repl.co/:151:12)
        at handleEvents (https://kaboomjs.com/lib/0.5.0/kaboom.js:55:19852)
        at https://kaboomjs.com/lib/0.5.0/kaboom.js:56:181
        at frame (https://kaboomjs.com/lib/0.5.0/kaboom.js:55:3425)
```

JavaScript:

```js
    kaboom({
      global: true,
      fullscreen: true,
      scale: 1,
      debug: true,
      clearColor: [0,0,0]
    })

    const MOVE_SPEED = 120
    const JUMP_SPEED = 800

    loadSprite('tubo_sinistra', 'https://i.imgur.com/YVW4m89.png')
    loadSprite('tubo_punta_sinistra', 'https://i.imgur.com/JcvhMs4.png')
    loadSprite('tubo_punta_destra', 'https://i.imgur.com/wHB9HzE.png')
    loadSprite('tubo_destra', 'https://i.imgur.com/Drs3q84.png')
    loadSprite('player', 'https://i.imgur.com/MOOR8tT.png')


    scene("game", ({ level, score }) => {
      layer(['bg', 'obj', 'ui'], 'obj')
          
      const maps = [
        [
          '    sd   sd   sd   sd   sd   sd   sd   sd   sd   sd  ',
          '    sd   sd   sd   sd   sd   sd   sd   sd   sd   sd  ',
          '    sd   sd   sd                                     ',
          '    sd   sd   sd                                     ',
          '    sd        sd                                     ',
          '              sd                                     ',
          '                                                     ',
          '         sd                                          ',      
          '    sd   sd                                          ',
          '    sd   sd   sd                                     ',
          '    sd   sd   sd   sd   sd   sd   sd   sd   sd   sd  ',
          '    sd   sd   sd   sd   sd   sd   sd   sd   sd   sd  ',
        ],
      ]

      const levelCfg = {
        width: 48,
        height: 48,
        's': [sprite('tubo_sinistra'), solid(), 'wall',scale(4)],
        'd': [sprite('tubo_destra'), solid(), 'wall', scale(4)],
      }

      addLevel(maps[level], levelCfg)

      //add([sprite('bg'), layer('bg')])

      const player = add([
        sprite('player'),
        scale(2.5),
        pos(5, 190),
        //body(),
        {
          // right by default
          dir: vec2(1,0),
        }
      ])

      player.action(() => {
        player.resolve()
      })
          
      player.collides('wall', () => {
        destroy(player)
      })

      player.action(() => {
        player.move(MOVE_SPEED,0)
      })

      keyPress('space', () => {
        player.jump()
      })

          
    })

    scene("lose", ({ score }) => {
      add([text(score, 32), origin('center'), pos(width()/ 2, height() /2)])
    })

    start("game", { level: 0, score: 0})
```

HTML:

```html
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Flappy Bird
        </title>
        <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://kaboomjs.com/lib/0.5.0/kaboom.js"></script>
        <script src="flappy_bird.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Straight from [the documentation](https://kaboomjs.com/):

> ```
> // .jump() is provided by body() component
> ```

You seem to have commented yours out in your definition of `player`:

```
const player = add([
    sprite('player'),
    scale(2.5),
    pos(5, 190),
    //body(),
    {
      // right by default
      dir: vec2(1,0),
    }
])
```

Un-comment `body()` - that should make that method available again on `player`.

Comment: Oh God thank you such a stupid error